# WPF- Cannot update ListView with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a usercontrol with different buttons in a ListView. If I instantiante my observable list and add some items I can update. But if I instantiate it after I pressed the button it doesn't update the GUI.

```
class ModelViewA {
 private ObservableCollection<ObjectA> myList;
 public ObservableCollection<ObjectA> MyItems {get {return myList;} set {myList = value;}}
 private void OnConfigCommand(int numbers)
 {   
   myList = new ObservableCollection<ObjectA>();
   for(int i = 0; i <  numbers; i++)
   {
     myList.Add(new Object() { Name="Name" }); 
   }
  }

}
    class ObjectA : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
      get { return name; }
      set
         {
           if (name != value)
           {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
           }
         }
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
                }
            }
    }

<ListView x:Name="m_List" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="DimGray" Margin="0,5,0,0" Height="250">
          <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False" >
              <GridViewColumn  Header="Name" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path= Name}"/>
              <GridViewColumn Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ButtonName}" >
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                  <Button Width="76" Height="110" Content="ButtonName" Tag="0" ToolTip="Click here to import data from *.ini file."  Command="{Binding OnConfigCommand}" CommandParameter="0"/>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
              </GridViewColumn>
             </GridView>
          </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
```

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to post a good answer. That said, if by _"instantiate it after"_, you mean you are setting the `MyItems` property later, after the binding has been set up, then I wouldn't expect the bound value to update, since your `ModelViewA` class doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: yeah I know it is hard but I cannot post the whole code. Yes that was what I meant. I also tried it like that but that also didn't work out. But thanks for your help. Guess better to change the GUI and set my items before the binding.

Comment: I suspect the UpdateSourceTrigger on the ListView to be (part of) the problem. Have you tried different settings there? (In addition to what Peter said)

Comment: you need to let the gui know that your collection has changed. raise property changed event in setter of the MyItems property

Comment: _"I cannot post the whole code"_ -- no one wants you to. Please read [mcve], so you understand what kind of code example is needed. See also [ask], for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way, and the articles linked at the bottom of that page for additional information about how to provide a good code example for a question.

Comment: Just worked it out! You were right. I forget to delete another method call to instantiate the list. Now it ist working with INotifyPropertyChanged in ModelViewA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the INotifyPropertyChanged also for class ModelViewA

```
class ModelViewA : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

and define the events like you already did for the ObjA class.

Then for the itemsource of your listview do this:

```
public ObservableCollection<ObjectA> MyItems 
  {
     get {return myList;} 
     set {
           myList = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("MyItems");
         }
  }
```

The problem is that you notify your UI that the items inside Mylist change, but you are not notifying that MyItems is changing.

Comment: Yes, and the confusion may be that of course you don't need to raise property changed events if the content of the observable collection changes.  However, here the actual observable collection itself is being replaced.  Personally I believe that you should never allow an observable collection to be replaced after instantiation to avoid this confusion - make a supporting readonly field for this collection, and make your setter just perform a clear and add the given items one-by-one.

Comment: Maybe it's a better practice to clear and add all over again, but i hardly see any difference. I always handle my collection like i explained in my answer. However, independently on how you handle the setter the OP need to implement INotyfyPropertyChanged

Comment: Your answer was perfectly valid, and I've given you an upvote for it, I was just trying to add something extra for the OP to consider.